# Why does $\gcd(c_1,c_2,\ldots ,c_k)=1\Rightarrow \gcd(c_1-c_2,c_2, \ldots ,c_k)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Let $c_i\in \mathbb{N}$ and $c_1\geq c_2$. Why does $\gcd(c_1,c_2,\ldots ,c_k)=1\Rightarrow \gcd(c_1-c_2,c_2, \ldots ,c_k)=1$?

Comment: Immediate from Bezout.

Comment: @Phicar I think you mean $p \mid (c_1-c_2)$ and $p$ divides from $c_3$ onwards. You cannot have $p \mid c_2$.

Comment: @Haran, notice that $c_2$ is there.

Comment: Oops, then it is my bad...

Comment: Well, then @user10354138 is right, didn't notice that right. This would follow from Bezout's, or to simply say, the Euclidean Algorithm

Comment: I was able to understand Phicar's proof, but I can't see why it also follows from Bézout's identity. Could you elaborate @user10354138?

Comment: Bezout's identity has the following corollary: $c_i$ coprime iff $1$ can be written as $\alpha_1 c_1+\alpha_2c_2+\dots+\alpha_k c_k$, some $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Now just manipulate $\alpha_1 c_1+\alpha_2c_2+\alpha_3 c_3+\dots+\alpha_k c_k=\alpha_1(c_1-c_2)+(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)c_2+\alpha_3 c_3+\dots+\alpha_kc_k$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $gcd(c_1-c_2,c_2,\cdots ,c_k)>1,$ then there exists a prime $p$ such that $p| c_1-c_2$ and $p|c_k$ for $k\geq 2.$ Conclude that $p|c_1.$